# чередованіе «о» въ безударной позиціи съ «а» въ ударной

Tags: историческая-фонетика

Какова исторія возникновенія сего чередованія?

(Возможно изъ заявленнаго въ темѣ будутъ исключенія)

Примѣръ: смотрѣть - разсматривать, топтать - вытаптывать.

Answer (score 0):

Существуют ли правила, регулирующие, когда о должно (или не должно) меняться на а?

Действующим правилом, регулирующим, будет ли меняться а на о, является следующее:

1. Если в глаголе совершенного вида ударение падает не на корневой гласный о, то в парном глаголе несовершенного вида вместо о появляется а. Это правило в настоящее время в литературном языке не знает исключений. Например: в глаголе совершенного вида «отстоЯть» ударение падает не на корень, а на суффикс, следовательно, в глаголе несовершенного вида буква о корня сменится на а и образуется форма «отстАивать», корни соответственно «стой» и «стай». Аналогично: вЫсмотреть — высмАтривать, корни «смотр» и «сматр»; затормозИть — затормАживать, корни «тормоз» и «тормаж».

Обратите внимание: нельзя проверять слова путём подбора глагола несовершенного вида, так как при этом буква корня меняется с о на а.

2. Если же корневой гласный в глаголе совершенного вида находится под ударением, чередования в несовершенном виде происходить не должно, например: обезбОлить — обезбОливать, уполномОчить — уполномОчивать.

Обратите внимание на формулировку правила 2: в нём сказано — «происходить не должно», но тенденция к замене -о- на -а- в глаголах несов. вида оказалась такой сильной, что охватила почти всю эту группу глаголов. В ряде случаев глаголы, у которых еще в начале ХХ в. зарегистрированы формы с -о-, теперь употребляются только с -а-, а прежний вариант воспринимается как искусственный и устарелый: если, к примеру, в начале прошлого века формы «освОивать» и «дотрОгиваться» были нормальными, то сейчас мы говорим только «освАивать», «дотрАгиваться». Поэтому обозначим третье правило:

3. Под влиянием тенденции к замене о на а ряд слов пишется с буквой а, хоть корень и находится под ударением, например: облагорОдить — облагорАживать (сравните корни!); заморОзить — заморАживать(сравните корни!). Эти слова  — исключения из правила 2, их достаточно много.
4. К этому пункту правила типу глаголы (их более 20), которые еще в начале ХХ в. писались только с -о-, теперь колеблются в употреблении. В этих парах вариантов сохраняется/наблюдается/отмечается стилистическое размежевание. Это значит, что у слов отмечается либо разговорный оттенок, либо книжный, либо слово считается устаревающим, и здесь нет единой информации: сколько словарей, столько и мнений. Вам скорее всего известно, что существуют пары от «обуслОвить(ся)» — обуслОвливать(ся) и обуслАвливать(ся), от «сосредотОчить(ся)» — сосредотОчиваться(ся) и сосредотАчивать(ся). При этом в одних словарях эти формы равнозначны, а в других указывается, что современная норма допускает только одну форму.

https://rus-ege.sdamgia.ru/handbook?id=283&print=true

```
  какова исторія возникновенія сего чередованія?
```

Историческая причина чередования: в индоевропейском языке существовали долгие и краткие гласные, которые чередовались в одном слове:
[О]//[О долг.] (позже ОàО, О долг. à А),
[А]//[А] долг. (позже АàО, А долг. à А), так вместо [О]//[О долг. ] появилось черед [О]//[А] и вместо [А]//[А долг. ] тоже [О]//[А]

> § 85. Судьба индоевропейских долгих и кратких гласных отражается в
>   общеславянских чередованиях гласных звуков, связанных с
>   индоевропейскими чередованиями. Праславянский язык унаследовал от
>   индоевропейской эпохи ряд морфологических чередований гласных звуков,
>   которые впоследствии видоизменились в соответствии с изменением самих
>   индоевропейских гласных в праславянском языке. Эти чередования могли
>   быть количественными и качественными.
>
> Количественными принято называть чередования _ одинаковых по качеству
>   (по образованию), но разных по"продолжительности звучания гласных
>   (например, чередование *1 и *?, т. е. долгого и краткого гласных
>   одного качества).§ 86. Наиболее распространенными были индоевропейские
>   количественные чередования, унаследованные праславянским языком и
>   соответствующим образом в нем изменившиеся.
>
> *0Ц*о > [о]//[а]. Такое чередование характеризовало глагольные основы со значением недлительного, однонаправленного действия (краткий
>   гласный) и длительного, иногда — повторяющегося действия (долгий
>   гласный); это же чередование можно наблюдать и в основах
>   существительных, образованных от глаголов. Так как в праславянском
>   языке позднего периода *o > [о], *o > [а] (см. § 77—78), то
>   индоевропейское (раннее праславянское) чередование краткого и долгого
>   *о изменилось в общеславянское качественно-количественное чередование [о]//[а]: старослав. скотити — скакати (в начале праславянской эпохи
>   *-skok-//*-skok-), русск. вскочит — скачет^ старослав. просити — въпрашати, русск. просит — спрашивать.

https://studopedia.net/1_38222_tema--foneticheskie-zakonomernosti-v-oblasti-glasnih-i-soglasnih.html

Comment: В § 85 форма «чередование [о]//[а]» должна быть примером написания. Уж больно несерьёзно выглядят записи типа «меняется с о на а».

Comment: Это почему же несерьёзно? В учебнике для студентов  "Введение в языкознание  " :Такое явление называется чередованием звуков, или альтернацией (от лат. alternatio – "чередование, смена"). Чередование обычно определяется как взаимозамена звуков в рамках определенной морфемы. Ещё :"ЧЕРЕДОВАНИЕ – взаимозамена звуков в пределах одной и той же морфемы в разных словах или словоформах", "взаимозамена звуков в пределах морфемы в разных случаях ее употребления ", "замена одних звуков другими в одной и той же части слова", происходящая...".https://studme.org/81691/literatura/cheredovanie_zvukov

Comment: Так что чередование - это замена, при определённых условиях звуки в одной морфеме меняются с одного на другой. Всё терминологически верно.Происходит чередование или нет = меняется звук или нет.

Comment: Не стоит так в штыки принимать это моё замечание: оно относится лишь к форме записи. В ответе у Вас их три, кроме указанных «[о]//[а]», «о, а», ещё и «-о- и -а-». Не к месту кудряво; понимаю, что из разных источников, но Вы же их свели в один текст...

Comment: Простите, перечитала и не увидела  «о, а»,  если Вы имеете в виду "позже АàО, А долг. à А ", это пояснение к долгим звукам, как по-другому здесь напишешь, у нас нет теперь долгих гласных?     И это тоже обозначены отдельные звуки, а не чередования: «-о- и -а-». Кстати, это тоже в учебнике, только другом, Вы правы.